# How to lock when creating table in sql server?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to run this query on a multiple instances (on a server) of the same application

I tried to run the query but would get deadlocks.

```
set transaction isolation level serializable
go
begin transaction
if not exists (select name from sys.sysobjects where name like 'xyp')
begin
    CREATE TABLE xyp( id varchar(1), name varchar(5));
end
commit transaction go
```

Is there anything that I can do?

Comment: [This DBA Stack Exchange question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60590/lock-create-table) basically answers your concerns.  You may try creating a lock on the entire create operation.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to lock the table during the creation? i don't think it can be done in sql server. you need to make some changes against your app.